# I need Mongo db query for nested join. There are 4 collection customer, order, orderDeatils & products

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need Mongo db query for nested join. There are 4 collection customer, order, orderDeatils & products
I need the result as mensioned bellow.

customer collection

```
[{
  customerId: "1232"
  name: "name A",
  email: "nameA@gmail.com"
}]
```

order collection

```
[{
  orderId: "123",
  date: "05-01-2024",
  customerId: "1232"
}]
```

orderDeatils collection

```
[{
    orderId: "123",
    productId: "123",
    quantity : 2
 
},
{
    orderId: "123",
    productId: "124",
    quantity : 3
 
}
]
```

product collection

```
[{
  productId: "123",
  name: "mobile A"
},
{
  productId: "124",
  name: "mobile B"
}
]
```

expected Result :

```
  {
    orderId: "123",
    date: "05-01-2024",
    customerId: "1232",
    customerName: "name A",
    customerEmail: "nameA@gmail.com",
    productsList : [
        [{
          productId: "123",
          name: "mobile A"
          quantity : 2
        },
        {
          productId: "124",
          name: "mobile B",
          quantity : 3
        }
        ]
    ]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This aggregation below should do.

```js
db.order.aggregate([
  {
    // $lookup is a join-like operator
    $lookup: {
      from: "customer",
      localField: "customerId",
      foreignField: "customerId",
      as: "customerInfo"
    }
  },
  {
    // The result of a $lookup is an array, so we have to use unwind to transform an array
    // of object into one document per array entry. Even though it seems it's a one-to-one
    // relationship, it's needed to transform an one size array into an object.
    $unwind: "$customerInfo"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "orderDetails",
      localField: "orderId",
      foreignField: "orderId",
      as: "orderDetails"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "product",
      localField: "orderDetails.productId",
      foreignField: "productId",
      as: "productsList"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      // Group based on the granularity of an order
      _id: "$orderId",
      date: { $first: "$date" },
      customerId: { $first: "$customerId" },
      customerName: { $first: "$customerInfo.name" },
      customerEmail: { $first: "$customerInfo.email" },
      productsList: { $push: "$productsList" }
    }
  },
  {
    // Do the $project lastly since the database loses the capability of using indexes
    // after this aggregation step
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      orderId: "$_id",
      date: 1,
      customerId: 1,
      customerName: 1,
      customerEmail: 1,
      productsList: 1
    }
  }
]);
```

Reference Docs:

- [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)
- [$group](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)
- [$project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Comment: Quantity is missing